# Converting MySQL POINT datatype to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I am migrating a database with geometric data from MySQL to PostgreSQL. I've run into a snag because the POINT datatypes are incompatible between the two databases.

In MySQL, the POINT values are single hex strings like `0xE21D4B40`. However, I cannot insert these into PostgreSQL because [PostgreSQL's POINT datatype](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-geometric.html) expects coordinates in the form of `(x,y)`. What is the best way to handle this conversion?

Comment: You [probably have to unpack those values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fetching-spatial-data.html) before you can insert them on the Postgres side.

Comment: Yeah, looks like that's the easiest way. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you do figure out the exact way to do it, would be worth posting an answer here for posterity.

Comment: Definitely, I've done so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@tadman's comment ended up being my solution: unpacking the hex string to a pair of values on the MySQL side. In my case the hex string was a column called `location` in the `city` table, so I used the query `SELECT ST_AsText(location) FROM city;`.

This returned rows like `POINT(-133.03531 54.23346)` which PostgreSQL was happy to accept.